# What is the difference between requests, requests2, and requests3?

Tags: python, python-requests

I use `requests` quite regularly. Recently I discovered there is also a `requests2` and an upcoming `requests3`

While there's a [page](https://www.kennethreitz.org/requests3) which briefly mentions what's coming in `requests3`, I've been unable to determine what `requests2` is and why I'd use that over `requests`.  I'm assuming the 2 means its a newer better version, maybe?

Requests2

- Has a better looking [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/requests2/) page
- Looks like it has the same but older changes from `requests`

Otherwise I could find no other information.  Could someone explain the differences between `requests` and `requests2` and for the sake of completeness `requests3`?

Comment: check the history of each- [`requests2`](https://pypi.org/project/requests2/#history) is just a version of [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/#history) from May. The ugly page for requests is because the new PyPI service that was just released has issues rendering restructured text. It will probably be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that `requests`, `requests2` and `requests3` are all owned by Kenneth Reitz.

They all point to `requests`.

I'd imagine that at some point in the past, there were plans to create a new package for version 2, `requests2` but it seems to have been discontinued a year ago. Now, `requests2` is just a not up-to-date `requests`.

As for `requests3`, it seems that Kenneth wants to create the version 3 of `requests`, which will probably not be backward compatible with the version 2. Most notably, it will have `async`/`await`, which it is terribly lacking right now.

Will it be a new package, named `requests3` (which he already owns)? Or will it just be a version 3 in `requests`? I wouldn't bet on it. But, I'd guess that the tendency is to create new versions in the same package, nowadays. So, if I really really had to bet on it, I'd say it'll be on `requests` with version 3.